# GAE Flask Oauth2Decorator 500 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-api, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use Oauth2Decorator to authorize application - running as flask application in gae.

I created client-id and client-secret for the project also enabled the API's in the console.

Below is the simple function for which decorator is added. So, when user visits the url it should redirect to authentication but it is showing 500 Internal Server Error.

Any suggestions why 500 error was thrown ??

```
from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import OAuth2Decorator
decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
      client_id="abcde.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      client_secret="yyyyyy",
      scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks")

@app.route("/")
@decorator.oauth_required
def welcome():
    try:
        #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return "Hi Welcome"
    except Exception as e:
        print e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: The decorator order matters, maybe try swapping `@app.route("/")` with `@decorator.oauth_required`?

Comment: Also, the 5XX error codes indicate something happend server-side. You must always check the app's logs to find out more details.

Comment: Ya I tried swapping decorator with app, if we do so - decorator is not applied  to the function

Comment: I have also check the logs , there is no error in app's log. As it is simple function , I don't see any errors in it.

Comment: `import OAuth2Decoratorenter` is that what you have in your code?  Shouldn't that be `import OAuth2Decorator`?

Comment: No its OAuth2Decorator only, here I am wrongly mistyped

Answer (score 1):

The `oauth_required` decorator can only be used to decorate a method of a `webapp.RequestHandler` instance, not an arbitrary method - it actually uses that instance. Which *might* make it incompatible with Flask.

Check the doc string for the `method` arg in the [`OAuth2Decorator.oauth_required` source code](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/oauth2client/contrib/appengine.html#OAuth2Decorator.oauth_required):

```
def oauth_required(self, method):
    """Decorator that starts the OAuth 2.0 dance.

    Starts the OAuth dance for the logged in user if they haven't already
    granted access for this application.

    Args:
        method: callable, to be decorated method of a webapp.RequestHandler
                instance.
    """
```

Comment: Ohh thanks for the reference, Dan. In that case what to do if we run the flask application instead of webapp2

Comment: Not sure, I'm not familiar w/ flask. You could look for a flask-specific decorator, there *might* be one available. It *might* also be possible to adapt that decorator and/or write your own from scratch.